# CS50 Finance KeyError

Tags: finance, cs50

Nomatter what I do, I keep getting issues with a Keyerror on my /buy.

```
db.execute("INSERT INTO transactions (ticker, shares, price, id, transaction) VALUES(:ticker, :shares, :price, :id, :transaction)", ticker=stock["ticker"], shares=shares, price=stock["price"], id=session["user_id"], transaction=now)
```

I keep getting the error message: KeyError: 'ticker'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably complaining about `ticker=stock["ticker"]`. I'm going out on a limb and suspect you want `stock['symbol']`, with the assumption that the stock array is built from `lookup`. If that's not the case, you'll need to edit the question to include more code, especially where `stock['ticker']` gets populated in relation to the insert.